# How to set FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON for a different app?

Tags: android, android-11

Is it possible to set the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON for a different app? I want to enable it for a 3rd-party app when my app is started and disable it when my app exits.

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#screen only shows me how to do that for my own app.

Comment: While I cannot rule out a solution on rooted devices, ordinary apps cannot modify flags for windows of other apps.

Comment: It's an internal app, so whatever required permissions are okay, but the devices are not rooted and it's not a system app.

Comment: Not specifically, you'll need a rooted device OR inflate a Overlay View via a foreground service and add relevant flags.

Comment: For our internal app an empty overlay view via a sticky service did the trick. Thank you very much. We based the code roughly on https://gist.github.com/bjoernQ/6975256